# How to determine the number of useful bits of a number?

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

I'm writing a function, which determine the number of useful bits of a 16 bits integer.

```
int16_t
f(int16_t x)
{
    /* ... */
}
```

For example, the number "00000010 00100101" has 10 useful bits. I think I should use some bitwise operators, but I don't know how. I'm looking for some ways to do it.

Comment: I had to reread your question a few times to figure out what it is you want, but you seem to be asking for the index of the highest bit that's set. This is equivalent to counting the number of leading zeros. You should be able to find lots of existing questions along these lines with good answers.

Comment: What is the function supposed to return for negative numbers?  Negative numbers will have leading ones that are perhaps not considered "useful".

Comment: Many thanks for your answers. The problem is, that it should work with negative number too. "11111111 11100101" should return 5 for example.

Comment: In that case, you want to count leading zeros, and if the result is 0 count leading ones. To count leading 1s you could for example count the leading zeroes of `~x`. There might be some clever trick to do both at once, but if you currently don't know *any* ways of doing it, it's probably best not to get too clever too soon ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using gcc (or a gcc-compatible compiler such as ICC) then you can use built in intrinsics, e.g.

```
#include <limits.h>

int f(int16_t x)
{
    return x != 0 ? sizeof(x) * CHAR_BIT - __builtin_clz(x) : 0;
}
```

This assumes you just want the number of bits to the right of the last leading zero bit.

For MSVC you can use `_BitScanReverse` with some adjustment.

Otherwise if you need this to be portable then you can implement your own general purpose `clz` function, see e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find_first_set

Comment: ffs, being a POSIX function, is preferable.

Answer (score 2):

These are called bitscan operations, and on intel architecture there are assembly instruction ( you can call directly from C ) [see here](http://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/BitScan#bsfbsr). If you are using a MS compiler s[tart from here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wfd9z0bb%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Logarithms compute the number of digits needed to represent a certain number to a certain base:

Let `[x]` be `x`, rounded to the next integer.

Then `[log_b(x)]` is the number of digits needed to represent `x` to base `b`.

Hence, if you want to know the number of significant bits of some `x` in C, then `ceil(log2(x))` will tell you.

Since there is no algorithm that will tell you the number of leading zeros of a binary representation in constant time, computing the logarithm may actually be faster than naively iterating.